# The result of zlib has different tail between python and php

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, compression, zlib

The php code is
'''

```
$input_file = "a.txt";
$source = file_get_contents($input_file);
$source = gzcompress($source);
file_put_contents("php.txt",$source)
```

'''

The python code is
'''

```
testFile = "a.txt"
content = None
with open(testFile,"rb") as f:
    content = f.read()

outContent = zlib.compress(content)
with open("py.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(outContent)
```

'''

The python3 version is [Python 3.6.9]
The php version is [PHP 7.2.17]

I need the same result for same md5.

Comment: I ran your codes and am getting the same md5sum for both languages: `792366c9e7780a21cb0fb0c61fb014b6`

Comment: I'm sorry.I forgot to say that only if the file is big the difference appears, You can try a file larger than 20 k.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in PHP or Python, but rather in your "need". You cannot expect to get the same result, unless the two environments happen to be using the same version of the same compression code with the same settings. Since you do not have control of the version of code being used, your "need" can never be guaranteed to be met.

You should instead be doing your md5 on the *decompressed* data, not the compressed data.

Comment: Thank you. I konw your point.But the old php script is being used in our porject for years. That would be a horrible thing if all the md5 change. I may try other way .

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.
The code is

```
        compress = zlib.compressobj(zlib.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,zlib.DEFLATED, 15, 9)
        outContent = compress.compress(content)
        outContent += compress.flush()
```

The python zlib provide a interface "zlib.compressobj",which returns a compressobj,and the parameters decide the result.
You can adjust parameters to make sure the python's result is same with php's